# Signing in throws 'Incorrect username or password' error when users log in

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I created a Cognito User Pool where users can sign up but can no longer sign in. I have attempted many different configurations, such as disabling MFA, turning off remembering of devices as I saw that can cause this issue, to no avail.

The weirdest thing is, that is works fine locally (`localhost:5000`). I can create accounts and login without any drama, but when I try to *login* on my site `https://example.com` (hosted on S3) it throws the above error. The users actually seem to get created in Cognito too if I signup - so that works, but the logins just don't work anywhere but locally.

I have double, triple checked every setting, env variable, recreated the user pool etc.

**Error**

This is the ambiguous error thrown when I attempt to login:

```
{
  __type: "NotAuthorizedException", 
  message: "Incorrect username or password."
}
```

**Pre-signup triggered lambda**

I am confirming the users before they sign up via lambda:

```
import {INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR} from 'http-status-codes';

export async function validateHumanViaSns(
    event: CognitoUserPoolTriggerEvent,
    context: Context,
    callback: Callback
): Promise<CognitoUserPoolTriggerHandler> {
    try {
        event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

        callback(null, event);

        return;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        callback(null, new Response(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, {message: 'Something went wrong'}));

        return;
    }
}
```

**package.json**

My client is using the latest [amplify-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js) library.

```
dependencies: {
  "amplify": "1.1.19" // broken since 1.1.18
}
```

**CloudFormation Cognito template**

```
UserPool:
  Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPool'
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: myapp-${self:provider.stage}-user-pool
    SmsVerificationMessage: 'Your verification code is {####}.'
    AutoVerifiedAttributes:
      - email
    MfaConfiguration: 'OFF'
    EmailVerificationSubject: 'Your MyApp verification code'
    EmailVerificationMessage: 'Your MyApp verification code is {####}.'
    SmsAuthenticationMessage: 'Your MyApp authentication code is {####}.'
    Schema:
      - Name: name
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
      - Name: email
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: false
        Required: false
      - Name: phone_number
        AttributeDataType: String
        Mutable: true
        Required: false
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        RequireLowercase: true
        RequireSymbols: false
        RequireNumbers: true
        MinimumLength: 8
        RequireUppercase: true
    AdminCreateUserConfig:
      InviteMessageTemplate:
        EmailMessage: 'Your MyApp username is {username} and temporary password is {####}.'
        EmailSubject: 'Your temporary MyApp password'
        SMSMessage: 'Your MyApp username is {username} and temporary password is {####}.'
      UnusedAccountValidityDays: 7
      AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: false

# Creates a User Pool Client to be used by the identity pool
UserPoolClient:
  Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient'
  Properties:
    ClientName: myapp-${self:provider.stage}-web-client
    GenerateSecret: false
    UserPoolId:
      Ref: UserPool

# Creates a federeated Identity pool
IdentityPool:
  Type: 'AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool'
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolName: MyApp{self:provider.stage}Identity
    AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true
    CognitoIdentityProviders:
      - ClientId:
          Ref: UserPoolClient
        ProviderName:
          'Fn::GetAtt': [ UserPool, ProviderName ]

# Create a role for unauthorized access to AWS resources. Very limited access. Only allows users in the previously created Identity Pool
CognitoUnAuthorizedRole:
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Principal:
            Federated: 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com '
          Action:
            - 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com :aud':
                Ref: IdentityPool
            'ForAnyValue:StringLike':
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com :amr': unauthenticated
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: 'CognitoUnauthorizedPolicy'
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: 'Allow'
              Action:
                - 'mobileanalytics:PutEvents'
                - 'cognito-sync:*'
              Resource: '*'

# Create a role for authorized access to AWS resources. Control what your user can access. This example only allows Lambda invokation
# Only allows users in the previously created Identity Pool
CognitoAuthorizedRole:
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Principal:
            Federated: 'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com '
          Action:
            - 'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com :aud':
                Ref: IdentityPool
            'ForAnyValue:StringLike':
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com :amr': authenticated
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: 'CognitoAuthorizedPolicy'
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: 'Allow'
              Action:
                - 'mobileanalytics:PutEvents'
                - 'cognito-sync:*'
                - 'cognito-identity:*'
              Resource: '*'
            - Effect: 'Allow'
              Action:
                - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
              Resource: '*'

# Assigns the roles to the Identity Pool
IdentityPoolRoleMapping:
  Type: 'AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment'
  Properties:
    IdentityPoolId:
      Ref: IdentityPool
    Roles:
      authenticated:
        'Fn::GetAtt': [ CognitoAuthorizedRole, Arn ]
      unauthenticated:
        'Fn::GetAtt': [ CognitoUnAuthorizedRole, Arn ]
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this particular error is thrown (I think it's misleading) or even better, how to fix this?

Comment: This looks like a widespread issue that hasn't been resolved (surprise!) for > 7 months: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1181

Comment: What about Amplify versions being used in the S3 website? There must be some env difference b/w those 2. As this works from local site, this is not a service issue or userpool configuration for sure.

Comment: @agent420 I lock all my versions down, plus I've checked most times re:versions over the last few weeks.

Comment: Could be due to an outdated SDK/lib? I see that u have checked env, settings tec. but I would still suggest checking and comparing the 2 environments. I built a PoC using Amplify JS and did not see any issue so it must be something env specific

Comment: Well, then this is a pretty weird error.

Comment: Could u add the amplify version used, just for reference?

Comment: Added! amplify @ 1.1.19 (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188326/discussion-between-agent420-and-matt-rowles).

Comment: @agent420 looks like it was actually an issue, see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed over in the AWS Amplify Github issue backlog, [more context here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1181).

Wherever you import amplify, you need to import a `crypto-js` dependency directly beforehand, due to Typescript compilation issue in the amplify-js library:

```
import 'crypto-js/lib-typedarrays'; // add this line
import Amplify, {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
```

It looks like this will be a permanent fix in a *future* pull request, so depending on when you land here, try updating the `aws-amplify` package to something > `1.1.19` first, to see if it's been fixed in the main package first.